# Create / Rename a tempfile in rails using open() method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am trying to create a tempfile, which i am downloading from a URL: for example this JPEG image which has no extension in the URL:

http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/jewelrymedia/Verragio14123_V_918_CU7

You can see it does not have a .jpg extension... So i'd like to save it as a tempfile, but before saving append the .jpg extension to it. Is this possible? Or if thats not possible, rename the tempfile after saving?

Right now, i am able to create the temp file by saying

`file = open("http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/jewelrymedia/Verragio14123_V_918_CU7")`

Which writes the temp file... But this does not help, as the temp file also has no extension

`#<Tempfile:/var/folders/3m/t1v11gzj32n0fdbhwr823y600000gn/T/open-uri20150309-21935-qw7870>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca6b174078fa15f33655be704d9409fdbc4f9929/lib/open-uri.rb#L393) you can't specify extension for Tempfile downloaded through `open-uri`.

So, just create new Tempfile with `.jpg` extension and write downloaded file to it:

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'open-uri'

input_file = open('http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/jewelrymedia/Verragio14123_V_918_CU7')

output_file = Tempfile.new(['output', '.jpg'])

output_file.binmode
output_file.write input_file.read
output_file.flush

output_file.seek(0)

p output_file.path
p output_file.size
```

Comment: I was on the right track... i had something similar started, and you got me on the right path. thanks!